# How to fix error ininitialize vector of struct

Tags: c++, vector, c++98

This is my code. (C++98)

```
struct node
{
    string name;
    string help;
    string action;
    string pName;
    string pHelp;
};

vector<node> commands {
    node{"name1", "help1", "", "", ""},
    node{"name2", "help2", "action2", "pname", "phelp"}
};
```

The error is

> function definition does not declare parameters

Comment: You have to write a `node` constructor for with 5 parameters. Also your code is not C++98.

Comment: @S.M Thank you. I'm new in c++. Is this code wrong?

Comment: It's wrong C++98. The constructs you use in C++ now often depend on dialect

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using an old compiler but following new tutorial or book. gcc 5.4.0 gives this:

```
test.cpp:12:27: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
    vector <node> commands {
                           ^
test.cpp:13:10: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
      node{"name1","help1", "", "" , ""}, node{"name2", "help2","action2",    "pname", "phelp"}
          ^
test.cpp:13:46: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
      node{"name1","help1", "", "" , ""}, node{"name2", "help2","action2",    "pname", "phelp"}
                                              ^
test.cpp:14:6: error: in C++98 ‘commands’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’
      };
```

Which clearly says that you either have to use c++11 at least or need to provide a constructor for `node` that takes five parameters and use the old style to construct objects.

Unless you have very specific reasons to stick to c++98, I would say that moving to C++11 is the best option. Otherwise please follow books or tutorials that teach C++98 or at least describe how things were different in C++98 to avoid such problems.